# Determine coding of text

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm getting some weird characters as a response to a webpage. I'm pretty sure its a message in Russian language, but the coding seems to be all weird. The webpage info tells me the the encoding is ISO-8859-1. Here is the sample response.

```
Âû ñòðàíè÷êå ïðåâüþøêàìè
```

Is there a way to decrypt this response? Is the response salvageable at all.

Comment: I'm getting the response as byte string. Now that I know the encoding, how can I decode the text using a python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the encoding is actually Cyrillic Windows-1251.  Switch your web-browsers encoding accordingly.

For example, the text you supplied in that encoding is:

> Вы страничке превьюшками

which an auto-translation says means "You page previews".

Answer (score 3):

It is hardly possible to automatically recognize 8-bit encodings because all byte combinations are technically valid. In this case, I'm pretty sure it is [Windows-1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251), because the characters are quite meaningful there:

> Вы страничке превьюшками

It's clearly not ISO-8859-1.

For converting this into a Unicode string, use the `decode` method:

```
b = "Âû ñòðàíè÷êå ïðåâüþøêàìè".encode("Latin-1")  # simulate the incoming byte string
u = b.decode("Windows-1251")
print(u)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can encode/decode the text in a script, maybe python script?

Comment: Do you get the response as a byte string or as a Unicode string? Please add your comment to the question.

Comment: I'm getting a byte string. Added a comment to the original question.